# Protected video raw url inside Sitemap.xml

Tags: video-sitemap, video-hosting

All videos inside our site are protected and should be seen only by the users inside my country.

So all the raw video urls are protected by a content protection signature.

Given that we cannot add the raw video urls directly inside our sitemap, because for each raw video url we need to generate a signature based on the reader ip address in order to allow reader to get the content.

So, we are thinking to set up a "page" on our server that catch all the raw video urls and if user agent is a bot then forward it towards the real Server with all the additional info for content protection.

```
http://myserver/fakepage/video_id -- 302 --> http://videoserver/video_id.format?signature
```

The question is, in your experience, is this feasible? 
Would the bots accept as answer a redirect (301, 302) instead of the real raw video url?

Answer (score 1):

Google does not like URLs in sitemaps that redirect.   When [somebody tested that](https://moz.com/community/q/301-redirects-inside-sitemaps), they got a warning in Google Webmaster Tools:

> When we tested a sample of URLs from your Sitemap, we found that some URLs redirect to other locations. We recommend that your Sitemap contain URLs that point to the final destination (the redirect target) instead of redirecting to another URL.

Instead, I would recommend adding logic to your web server when the file itself is served.   Allow it to be served for the correct IP addresses or bot user agent, but return a `403 Forbidden` response otherwise.